# Unable to connect wifi and ethernet

Tags: wireless, networking, dell, ethernet

I have installed Ubuntu on my Dell Latitude e6400 laptop. However, I am unable to connect either with Ethernet or wifi. There are no drivers detected under additional drivers. I enabled networking and created a wireless connection under network connection. However, it did nothing. Ethernet shows: Wired connection 1 (1 day ago)—which was when I installed Ubuntu.

I also tried:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

but it returns "probe not available".

Comment: what is the output of `ifconfig` and `lshw -c network`

Comment: ipconfig returns No command 'ipconfig' found.lshw -c network retunrs network controller and other describtion of the controller. BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n wireless LAN controller.

Comment: its not ipconfig its `ifconfig` please edit your question and put all the details with your it.